# How do I set up an AWS RDS instance for production so that I can regularly read in custom data from my personal computer

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I have built a REST API in Spring that I am ready to deploy as the back-end for my company's website.  It utilizes a mySQL RDS instance to store data.  I'm going to host it on AWS and am currently in the process of learning how to do that.  I connect to my database with Spring's jdbc template and make SQL queries to create and edit tables.

There is a big concern I have that has not been addressed by any of the tutorials I've read: Once everything is up and running on AWS, I will not have direct access to the database anymore as it will only be accessible from behind a my REST API which makes the necessary queries.  And the REST API will only be accessible by the front end server (which is also on AWS).  But I will regularly need to read in custom data in different formats.

Currently it is very easy to do that, because I can read in a random excel file and directly call the methods that actually make SQL queries on startup of the server.  But that is because my test RDS database is publicly accessible.  And I am pretty sure that is terrible practice.

So how can I set things up on AWS so that I can still connect to my database from my laptop and make custom SQL queries to my database?

I am following this tutorial (https://keyholesoftware.com/2017/09/26/using-docker-aws-to-build-deploy-and-scale-your-application/) to get my REST service up and running, and will have to set up the RDS instance separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best choice I know of is to SSH into an EC2 then connect to RDS. If you're on Mac, Sequel Pro makes this easy since you can provide SSH settings along with your MySQL connection settings.

This can also be accomplished with an SSH port forwarding then you can use your local SQL client. Here's a link to an article that appears to have correct information [MySQL SSH Tunnel](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205408088-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel)

Only other secure option is to allow RDS connections from your IP. I can't verify that still works but my memory says I used to run my former companies RDS that way.

Comment: I'm going to allow connections from my IP since I've already written all the queries I would need in java so I wouldn't want to do it again in a SQL client.  Thanks